# Is there an iOS equivalent of NotificationListenerService in Android?

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I'm currently working on an application that would communicate with a hardware device which will notify user when receiving any incoming push notifications from any apps, such as Facebook, Twitter, Messages. I have done the Android version already, However, I'm not sure if it is possible in iOS.

Comment: Hey, Did you find any way to do it in iOS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out that there's a way to work on this. Apple actually provides a service called `Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS)` to communicate with BLE devices for all notification data. This is probably used by device like Pebble smart watch as well.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, it is not possible. iOS apps are sandboxing.

Comment: Another one comment answer!